# Display base64 encoded image on a browser when hitting a specific url

Tags: php, database, image, blob

I want to display a image that is encoded with base64_encode. The image is fetching from mysql db based on the id parameter passed through the URL. The Content-type has been set. Say i have a code in index.php file and i am hitting that file in browser with url localhost:8080/products_images/index.php?id=1000

```
header('Content-Type:image/png');
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
} 

$sql = "SELECT image FROM table WHERE id = ".(int)$id;

$image = $dbInstance->getArray($sql);
unset($sql);
echo '<img src="data:image/png; base64,'.$image[0]['image'].'"/>';
```

Instead of displaying the image on a browser, it says *The image “localhost:8080/products_images/index.php?id=1000” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.*

I know its happening because on a browser DOM, i can clearly see the image tag appearing like following `<img src="localhost:8080/products_images/index.php?id=1000">`
Instead of showing the encoded string to img src tag, its showing the whole URL. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your script doesn't actually output anything. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: hey, 
thanks for quickly replying  here. i have edited the code. please check it now.

Comment: @Juan yeah i am sure and tested that i am getting the correct base64 encoded image here.

Comment: This question is attracting too many low-quality answers. This should probably be flagged for moderation and ask that some form of protection be set to it.

Comment: Do you have some javascript that inserts this into the DOM?

Comment: @Juan may you please have a look on code? i have again updated to make it more clear.

Comment: @Juan no i don't have any js code instead hitting that index.php file and trying to display the base64 encoded image on browser

Comment: what's the type for the image column?

Comment: its blob @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: All I can think of is that you probably have something else above the header, maybe some HTML, could be a BOM (byte order mark) issue. Edit: and/or add an `exit;` at the end of your script. Or place the header just above the echo and with an `exit;`.

Comment: tried but unfortunately nothing happened. Same result. 
regarging BOM issue you are talking about, i checked there is no html above the header.

Comment: If you right click to see the view source you get the same as with inspect?

Comment: Also can you add a print_r($image[0]['image']) to see what comes out?

Comment: it displays encoded string @Juan

Comment: @Juan i tried urlencode the base64 string but no progress yet.

Comment: By the way, content type should be text/html, you are sending text not an image

Answer (score -3):

To send the image to the client, you might try to load the image from the string with `imagecreatefromstring` function then send it to the client with `imagepng` function, it should give you something like that:

```
<?php
    $data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
    . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
    . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
    . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    if ($im !== false) {

        header('Content-Type: image/png');

        // Send the image
        imagepng($im);

        imagedestroy($im);

    } else {

        echo 'An error occurred.';

    }
?>
```

I got it from the [php doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)